# Ctrl + Shift + 0 (Keyboard shortcut) hang Visual studio 2015, Skype

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, skype

Windows 10 Enterprise x64

Visual studio 2015

Skype 7.14.0.106

Language switch shortcuts:

- Language 1 "Ctrl + Shift + 8"
- Language 2 "Ctrl + Shift + 9"
- Language 3 "Ctrl + Shift + 0"

**Skype** 100% hang on "Ctrl + Shift + 8,9,0" if language switch (if current language is shortcut language - no hangs)

**Visual studio 2015** 99% hang on "Ctrl + Shift + 0"

*The program devenv.exe version 14.0.23107.0 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed*

What can I see/check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround of this issue (with cool history of this ms bug) with "autohotkey" see. bistrashkin comment.

https://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/hotkey-combination-hangs-Skype-on-Windows-10-TP/td-p/3862078/page/9

It helps me.

Answer (score 0):

May be solution for Visual Studio 2015

1. Install Visual Studio 2015 SP 1
2. I have 4 languages, but only 3 has short key. After assign for all 4 - no hangs